# How can we use EXEC sp_executesql for two dynamic SQL statements?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

tables:

```
create table TabA
             (ID int, Name varchar(20))
             insert into  TabA
             select 1,'ABC' union
             select 2,'DEF' union
             select 3,'GHD' 

create table TabB
             (ID int, Name varchar(20))
             insert into  TabA
             select 1,'XYZ' union
             select 2,'STF' union
             select 3,'LDZ' 

create table status
             (Result1 int,Result2 int )

Create table query(query1 varchar(1000),query2  varchar(1000))

             Insert into query(query1,query2)
             select  '''select COUNT(*) from TabA''','''select COUNT(* )from TabB'''
             select * from query
```

procedure:

```
create  Procedure [dbo].spStatus
AS
BEGIN

  SET NOCOUNT ON;


Declare  @sqlString1 nvarchar(1000)
    ,@sqlString2 nvarchar(1000)
     ,@col_value1 varchar(256) 
    ,@col_value2 varchar(256)

   select @sqlString1 = query1
         , @sqlString2 =query2         

      from Query


        EXEC sp_executesql                       

         @query=@sqlString1, --sql string is your full select  statement                       

           @params = N'@col_Value1 varchar(256)  OUTPUT',                

            @col_Value1 = @col_Value1 OUTPUT
           print(@sqlString1)

           --  @sqlString2, --sql string is your full select  statement                       

           --@params = N'@col_Value2 varchar(256)  OUTPUT',                

           -- @col_Value2 = @col_Value2 OUTPUT


        Insert Into dbo.Status(Result1,Result2 )
        Values(@col_Value1,@col_Value2)



End
```

It works if we use `@query=@sqlString1` only but I want both statement `@query=@sqlString1,@query=@sqlString2` should execute together.

Please help how can we use both statement to execute?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

Did you mean:

```
SET @sqlString1 = @sqlString1 + ';' + @sqlString2;

EXEC sp_executesql @query = @sqlString1 --...
```

Comment: You may encounter a problem if `@sqlString1 + ';' + @sqlString2` is too long to reside solely within `@sqlString1`.  Also, if either `@sqlString1` or `@sqlString2` is `NULL` then the entire result of the concatenation will be `NULL`, and no sql will run.

Comment: While true, I was just providing the basic methodology. While we're picking apart each other's answers, you should change your variable declaration to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` to avoid Msg 214.

Answer (score 1):

Concat the two queries together with a + (`@query=@sqlString1 + '; ' + @sqlString2)`

Then use two variables to capture the two counts into output variables

OR

```
Insert into query(query1,query2)
    EXEC  sp_executesql 'SELECT ( select COUNT(*) from TabA ) AS query1, ( select COUNT(*)from TabB )  AS query2'
```

... but really and truly dynamic SQL isn't needed for that at all.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
--add this
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
SET @SQL=ISNULL(@sqlString1,'')+';'+ISNULL(@sqlString2,'')

--change this
EXEC sp_executesql @query=@SQL
    ,@params = N'@col_Value1 varchar(256)  OUTPUT'
    ,@col_Value1 = @col_Value1 OUTPUT
```